# Multiple functions plotted as f(y) instead of f(x) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, graph

I'm new to Python so I hope you'll forgive my silly questions. I have read a dataset from excel with pandas. The dataset is composed by 3 functions (U22, U35, U55) and related same index (called y/75). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1O0C.png)

now I would like to "turn" the graph so that the index "y/75" goes on the y-axis instead of the x-axis, keeping all the functions in the same graph. The results I want to obtain is like in the following picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P6yq.png)

the code I've used is

```
var = pd.read_excel('path.xlsx','SummarySheet', index_col=0)
norm_vel=var[['U22',"U35","U55"]]
norm_vel.plot(figsize=(10,10), grid='true')
```

But with this code I couldn't find a way to change the axes. Then I tried a different approach, so I turned the graph but couldn't add all the functions in the same graph but just one by one

```
var = pd.read_excel('path.xlsx','SummarySheet', index_col=False)
norm_vel2=var[['y/75','U22',"U35","U55"]]
norm_vel2.plot( x='U22',  y='y/75', figsize=(10,10), grid='true' )
plt.title("Velocity profiles")
plt.xlabel("Normalized velocity")
plt.ylabel("y/75")
```

obtaining this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glD7h.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with dataframes plot. And to be honest, I've been stalking this question expecting that someone would give an obvious answer. But since no one has one (1 hour old questions, is already late for obvious answers), I can at least tell you how I would do it, without the plot method of the dataframe

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.grid(True)
plt.plot(var[['U22',"U35","U55"]],  var['y/75'])
plt.title("Velocity profiles")
plt.xlabel("Normalized velocity")
plt.ylabel("y/75")
```

When used to matplotlib, in which, you can have multiple series in both x and y, the instinct says that pandas connections (which are just useful functions to call matplotlib with the correct parameters), should make it possible to just call

```py
var.plot(x=['U22', 'U35', 'U55'], y='y/75')
```

Since after all,

```py
var.plot(x='y/75', y=['U22', 'U35', 'U55'])
```

works as expected (3 lines: U22 vs y/75, U35 vs y/75, U55 vs y/75). So the first one should have also worked (3 lines, y/75 vs U22, y/75 vs U35, y/75 vs U55). But it doesn't. Probably the reason why pandas documentation itself says that these matplotlib connections are still a work in progress.

So, all you've to do is call matplotlib function yourself. After all, it is not like pandas is doing much more when calling those `.plot` method anyway.